# AndroidManifest.xml not working properly

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

we are sooooo close to finishing our game, it is ready to be published through google play but we are having problems making any of the game services work.

we have a simple achievement button that should call the achievement UI, same goes for logging in. but we do not get any prompts when we are running it on our android device.

we have

PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

in our start function

```
 Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
     // handle success or failure
 });
```

connected to a log in button

and

Social.ShowAchievementsUI();

on our show achievement button.

our email is connected as a tester on google play and the game service API's are all enabled

my real question is about the AndroidManifest that the game play service for unity created.

this is it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!-- This file was automatically generated by the Google Play Games plugin for Unity
     Do not edit. -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" /> 

    <application>

     <!-- Required for Nearby Connections API -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.SERVICE_ID"
        android:value="" />

    <!-- the space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="\ 606268116612" /> 
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
            android:value="\ 606268116612" /> 
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
    <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application> 
</manifest>
```

i have read online that the package name should be our package name but shouldnt this be created when we run android set up using our ID number for our game? should i physically change this in code in the manifest even though it says i shouldnt edit it?

also OUR.ID i have replaced just for this question and in the real manifest has our actual ID No

Many Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

I always have the same package name (at application level) than my hierarchy in the project. In my opinion is a good practice to set the root at the folder where you have all your activities.

On the other hand, you can sign your app for market with the ID you want setting it in your gradle file.

You can see a good reference [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename).

I hope this would help you.